# Fill DataFrame, missing data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time, missing-data

## Description

I read a table with three columns: ID, time and location to create a dataframe. ID is the first index and time is the second index. I want the time frequency is five minute and if there is no data on the corresponding time, set the location to the last location(See the table below).

## The dataframe for now

```
ID   time          place
001  00:00:00      1
     00:15:00      3
002  00:05:00      2
```

## The dataframe I hope to get

```
ID   time          place
001  00:00:00      1  
     00:05:00      1
     00:10:00      1
     00:15:00      3
#continue to fill the table until 23:55:00   

002  00:00:00      2
     00:05:00      2
#continue to fill the table until 23:55:00
```

## Code

```
def create_table(n):
  table = pd.read_table(n,sep='\x01', header=None, names=['ID','time','place'])
  table['time'] = pd.to_datetime(table['time'], format='%H:%M:%S')
  table = table.set_index('ID','time')
  return table
```

I have no idea how to move on making the ideal dataframe. Can anyone give me some hints? Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the DataFrame you defined above, we can do:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['001', '001', '002'], 'time': ['00:00:00', '00:15:00', '00:05:00'], 'place': [1, 3, 2]}).set_index(['ID', 'time'])
```

In order to be able to work with just time and to apply the same operations to each of the ID values, let's unstack 'ID' so that we have a multi index of columns with our ID at the top level:

```
In [91]: df = df.unstack(0)

In [92]: df
Out[92]:
         place
ID         001  002
time
00:00:00   1.0  NaN
00:05:00   NaN  2.0
00:15:00   3.0  NaN
```

Now, let's cast our index (just 'time', now) to a DatetimeIndex:

```
In [93]: df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

In [94]: df
Out[94]:
                    place
ID                    001  002
time
2017-06-06 00:00:00   1.0  NaN
2017-06-06 00:05:00   NaN  2.0
2017-06-06 00:15:00   3.0  NaN
```

This adds today's date, but we can remove that later.

Next, let's create another DatetimeIndex consisting of 5-minute increments for today's date:

```
In [95]: times = pd.date_range("00:00:00", "23:55:00", freq="5min")

In [96]: times
Out[96]:
DatetimeIndex(['2017-06-06 00:00:00', '2017-06-06 00:05:00',
               '2017-06-06 00:10:00', '2017-06-06 00:15:00',
               '2017-06-06 00:20:00', '2017-06-06 00:25:00',
               '2017-06-06 00:30:00', '2017-06-06 00:35:00',
               '2017-06-06 00:40:00', '2017-06-06 00:45:00',
               ...
               '2017-06-06 23:10:00', '2017-06-06 23:15:00',
               '2017-06-06 23:20:00', '2017-06-06 23:25:00',
               '2017-06-06 23:30:00', '2017-06-06 23:35:00',
               '2017-06-06 23:40:00', '2017-06-06 23:45:00',
               '2017-06-06 23:50:00', '2017-06-06 23:55:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=288, freq='5T')
```

Let's reindex our df's index against this new DatetimeIndex:

```
In [97]: df = df.reindex(times)

In [98]: df
Out[98]:
                    place
ID                    001  002
2017-06-06 00:00:00   1.0  NaN
2017-06-06 00:05:00   NaN  2.0
2017-06-06 00:10:00   NaN  NaN
2017-06-06 00:15:00   3.0  NaN
2017-06-06 00:20:00   NaN  NaN
...
```

Now we just need to forward fill so that at each time, the location is the last non-NaN location:

```
In [99]: df = df.ffill()

In [100]: df
Out[100]:
                    place
ID                    001  002
2017-06-06 00:00:00   1.0  NaN
2017-06-06 00:05:00   1.0  2.0
2017-06-06 00:10:00   1.0  2.0
2017-06-06 00:15:00   3.0  2.0
2017-06-06 00:20:00   3.0  2.0
2017-06-06 00:25:00   3.0  2.0
2017-06-06 00:30:00   3.0  2.0
...
```

From here, we need to get rid of the dates:

```
In [101]: df.index = df.index.strftime('%H:%M:%S')

In [102]: df
Out[102]:
         place
ID         001  002
00:00:00   1.0  NaN
00:05:00   1.0  2.0
00:10:00   1.0  2.0
00:15:00   3.0  2.0
00:20:00   3.0  2.0
00:25:00   3.0  2.0
...
```

We've lost the name on our 'time' index, so let's put it back:

```
df.index = df.index.set_names('time')
```

And, finally, put 'ID' back into the index:

```
In [103]: df.stack(1).swaplevel(0, 1)
Out[103]:
              place
ID  time
001 00:00:00    1.0
    00:05:00    1.0
002 00:05:00    2.0
001 00:10:00    1.0
002 00:10:00    2.0
001 00:15:00    3.0
...
```

Comment: Really appreciate it!!